# HTML Table scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, tabular

I am creating a table in html (with mysql imports) but anyway, I want to show more content in the table than I can, so I want to create a scrollable table.

Normally my site looks like seen in the below link:

http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/3l/cc/8h/akvslq.jpg

But when I created `div with overflow`:

```
   .scrollit {
    overflow:scroll;
    height:100px; 
}
```

And added div into a code:

```
<div class="scrollit">
  <table>
    <tbody>
     .........
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

My site looks now like as seen in the below link:

http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/0p/vf/4i/pfmavw.jpg

And only title can be scrolled.

Whats wrong with that code?

Comment: you have to share more specific code..

Answer (score 0):

i think you mistyped the  tag

```
<div class="scrollit">
<table<tbody>
<mycode>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

should be

```
<div class="scrollit">
<table><tbody>
<mycode>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: did you use the <thead> tag within your table title?

Comment: @SlimDiverse you missing `thead` in your table structure.

Comment: Still same. Edited, added and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question exactly but if you want scroll bar only vertically then you should try below code :-

```
.scrollit {
  **overflow-y: scroll;**
  height:100px;
 }
```

or if you want your heading i.e., *Skin, Nick, Punkty* should be at their fixed position, then you have to use position: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">
    <table>
       <tbody>
        .........
       </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing tag is mismatching. Look at the following code you posted on pastebin.

```
  <div class="scrollit">
    <table style="margin-top: 22px; height: 100px;"><tbody style=""><tr>
     <th>Skin </th>
     <th> Nick </th>
     <th> Punkty </th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $link=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM statystyki ORDER BY punkty desc limit 30');
            while($ranking=mysql_fetch_array($link))
            {
            echo '

                    <tr>
                          <td style=" position: absolute; left: 550px; ">
                            <img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/'.$ranking['nick'].'/27" style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 2px;"> 
                            <a href="gracz.php?gracz='.$ranking['nick'].'">'.$ranking['nick'].'<br></a>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <a style="color: #434343; position: absolute; left: 800px;">'.$ranking['punkty'].'  </a> <br>
                          </td>
               <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                ';
            }
    ?>
                        </tbody></table></div>
```

In the above code look at the `while` loop part. You have started some `tr`, without closing the `tr` you have started one more `tr`. So here one `tr` closing is missing. I am not sure which way you want to create this. So close the `tr` in a proper way. After that your scrolling functionality will work in a proper way.

### EDIT

Based on your comment below, I have clean up your code and try it using like below.

```
  <div class="scrollit">
    <table style="margin-top: 22px; height: 100px;">
     <thead>
     <tr>
       <th width="33%">Skin </th>
       <th width="33%"> Nick </th>
       <th width="*" align="right"> Punkty </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="">
            <?php
                    $link=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM statystyki ORDER BY punkty desc limit 30');
                            while($ranking=mysql_fetch_array($link))
                            {
                            echo '

                                            <tr>
                                                  <td><img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/'.$ranking['nick'].'/27" style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 2px;"></td>
                                                  <td>

                                                            <a href="gracz.php?gracz='.$ranking['nick'].'">'.$ranking['nick'].'</a>
                                                      </td>
                                                      <td align="right">
                                                            <a style="color: #434343;">'.$ranking['punkty'].'  </a>
                                                      </td>
                                            </tr>
                <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                                    ';
                            }
            ?>
                                                    </tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Remvoe the `position:absolute` and `left:800px, left:550px` properties.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is some syntax issue in the HTML. The table tag is not closed. Please try the code below.

```
<div class="scrollit">
<table>
<tbody>
<mycode>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```